# UItableview sizing in interface builder

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a tableviewcontroller in the interface builder with a tableview in it.

In the IB I selected the tableviewcontroller and changed its width to 500 and height to 500.
I selected the tableview and changed it width to 500 and height to 500.

At this stage, I can see the width and height correctly on the storyboard.
Now I click one of the table cell in the IB and the width and height revert back to their normal values. Any idea how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

To reproduce the problem.

Step 1: Drag and drop a UITableviewController on the Storyboard (static cells + group)
Step 2: Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller
Step 3: Go to the property inspector of the Nav Controller and check Use explicit size > 600 x 500

Step 4: go to the property inspector of the TableViewController and check use explicit size > 600 x 500
Step 5: Select Table view and check use explicit size > 600 x 500

Step 6: Put a label inside one of the cells

At this point when you set the new size for the tableview..the storyboard reflects the new size.

Now click anywhere in the storyboard and back in one of the cells..
OOpps..the tableview reverts back to original dimensions..

However, the tableviewcontroller dimensions are intact in the IB.

Thanks in advance,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

Check anywhere in the code the frame of table set programmatically.

Comment: @Lithu.. I am just using the IB. I didnot type any code yet. Suprisingly when I click on the cell in IB, the size of the viewcontroller is not changing but the tableview in IB is reverting to its default size.

Comment: I am not sure..where can I check this?

Comment: Update: when I click the cell in the storyboard, the tableview reverts to the original size. If I now see in the menu > Edit > it says "undo change frame size"...Wow! why is the frame size changing when cell is clicked?